# Unable to redirect to profile page after signup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I simply want to redirect the user after signing up to the profile page after validation from NodeJS server file. I have passed the routes in index.js like this`

```
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './pages/home';
import Signup from './pages/signup';
import Signin from './pages/signin';
import Profile from './pages/profile';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
     <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
      <Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
      <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
     </div>
    </Router>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);`
```

. I have used `this.props.history` to redirect and also exported Signup component with `withRouter` and i troubleshot to see if Profile component mounts by passing `componentDidMount` hook but it does not. User data is saving fine on the database and it is giving an error:

> Here Request failed with status code 404

when i am trying to catch to the post request and

> xhr.js:173 GET http://localhost:3000/profile 404 (Not Found)

I have passed the `"proxy": "http://localhost:4000/"` in package.json and withRouter API in signup.js, however, it did not work.

> signup.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import queryString from 'querystring';

import { Link, withRouter, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class Signup extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      repassword: ''
    }
  }

  handleUsernameChange = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     this.setState({
       username: e.target.value
     })
  }

  handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      password: e.target.value
    })
  }


  handlePasswordConfirmChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      repassword: e.target.value
    })
  }


  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    axios.post('/signup', {
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password,
      repassword: this.state.repassword
    }).
      then( res => {
        this.props.history.push('/profile');
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Here', err.message);
    })
```

I tried Redirect API of react-router-dom by `importing Redirect from react-router-dom` and then replacing `this.props.history.push('\profile')` with `return <Redirect to='\profile' />` but it gave me `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /signup from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:4000/`.

> package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "query-string": "^6.4.2",
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },
```

Any help, suggestion will be appreciated, thanks in advance !!.

Comment: Open the dev tools in your browser and look at the Network tab. "404" errors generally mean your node.js server did not find the object you requested. Your client app actually asked for `/profile`. Does that match your expectation, or did you plan to serve that from `/pages/profile`?

Comment: @O.Jones  Yes, I planned to serve it from /pages/profile.